# Text appears when box is hovered over, but how to remove underline from text link?

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

I've been designing a website and have managed to make the background of the boxes fade when they are hovered over, with the text appearing at the same time. I am now adding links to the text, but cannot seem to remove the underline.

I would like to do two things here:

- Remove the underline when the text link is hovered over (I would like the text to be black)
- Make the text change colour when it is hovered over (to grey)

Your help is much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```css
.box-a {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box_a_background {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
    ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 1.0;
    background-position: 50% 40%;
  float: left;
}

.box-a:hover .box_a_background {opacity: 0.25;} 

.text-block-a {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 205px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
  color:#000;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  width: 50%;
}

.text-block-a a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet'>
 
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="content-area-group">

    <div class="box-a">
      <div class="text-block-a">  
        <h4><a href="#">Great cycle routes</h4>
          <p>Check out our guide to the best cycle routes in Nottinghamshire.</a></p>
        </div>
      <div class="box_a_background" style="background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/3Nm4HtNY/box-a-image-trent.jpg');"
    </div></div>


    
  </div>
  
  <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag in HTML defines a hyperlink, which default style is a blue text with an underline to signify to the user that the text can be clicked. To remove it, simply add this code into your CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This removes any pre-defined text decoration set for the `a` tag. `text-decoration` can add underline, overline, line-through, etc. to your text.

Answer (score 0):

I just added "text-decoration" and it is working, I also deleted an extra "div" element at the end.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box-a {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box_a_background {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
    ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 1.0;
    background-position: 50% 40%;
  float: left;
}

.box-a:hover .box_a_background {opacity: 0.25;} 

.text-block-a {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 205px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
  color:#000;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  width: 50%;
}

.text-block-a a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet'>
 
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="content-area-group">

    <div class="box-a">
      <div class="text-block-a">  
        <h4><a href="#">Great cycle routes</h4>
          <p>Check out our guide to the best cycle routes in Nottinghamshire.</a></p>
        </div>
      <div class="box_a_background" style="background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/3Nm4HtNY/box-a-image-trent.jpg');"
    </div>


    
  </div>
  
  <body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I add the mouse pointer when the link is hovered over?

Comment: You mean chancing  the cursor when your mouse pointer on the picture or you want to add a mouse cursor image down to picture when the link has hovered over?